Pine script — deleting old lines if a condition is met
I wonder if anyone could help me to fix/improve my code.
I'm trying to make an indicator that draws a line (at a certain 'priceY' level) whenever a condition is true, and then deletes it if a new price-low appears below the 'priceY' level of the line.
The part of the code that draws the lines is like this:
//@version=5
indicator("MyIndicator", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 3)

var line NewLine = na

if condition
       NewLine := line.new(bar_index, priceY, bar_index + 1, priceY, extend = extend.right, color = color.red, width = 1)

A line is correctly drawn for each instance of the condition, as expected. But I cannot get the indicator to delete all lines.
To delete the lines, I tried this:
//@version=5
indicator("MyIndicator", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 3)

var line NewLine = na

float CrossedLine = na

for i = 0 to 4999
    if condition
        NewLine := line.new(bar_index, priceY, bar_index + 1, priceY, extend = extend.right, color = color.red, width = 1)
    else if not na(NewLine[i])
        CrossedLine := line.get_y1(NewLine[i])
    if low < CrossedLine
        line.delete(NewLine[i])

That code deletes all lines above new lows, except the most recent line, even if a new low below that line does exist! Also, by using the 'for i = 0 to 4999', the execution time is greatly increased (and I think it would be worse if I add more lines to the indicator, each with its own execution/deletion code, but overall similar to the one above). Limiting the 'for i = 0 to 4999' to a lower number (like 'for i = 0 to 1500'), improves the execution time, but shows a weird behavior deleting some lines, but not all (including keeping some very old ones that I'd think were found beyond the scope of the code; also, as you can see, I tried to limit the max number of lines to only 3, expecting very old lines wouldn't show up anymore; but still, more than 3 lines are always drawn — usually, the condition is met a few dozen times in any chart.
I assume some more efficient option exists, but I cannot figure out what it is, or how to make it work.
I also tried an approach with arrays, like this:
var line NewLine = na

float OldLine = na


if condition
    NewLine := line.new(bar_index, priceY, bar_index + 1, priceY, extend = extend.right, color = color.red, width = 1)

for i = 0 to (array.size(line.all) == 0 ? na : array.size(line.all) - 1)
    OldLine := line.get_y1(array.get(line.all, i))

if low < labelText
    line.delete(NewLine)

With this approach, execution time is way faster, and now the most recent line is deleted (if a new low is below it). But this code forgets older lines. It only deletes newer ones (if a price-low below it appears, before a new line does).
I'm not sure if I missing something obvious, or if what I'm trying to achieve requires a more complex approach.
Another thing that I'm not sure if could be an issue, is that the full indicator includes code for other lines (like 'NewLine2', 'NewLine3', etc; though, for now, I put them away to focus on the problem described before). Those lines also should be deleted upon a new price-related condition (but because their conditions are different, I assume I should create an additional, slightly different, deletion code; that's why I'm not happy with the first attempt I mentioned: the execution time would become unbearable once applied to the whole code).
I'd appreciate any help, thanks.
